# Is it possible to specify global typings in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings, preact

I'm using Preact in the project, but I've configured the setup so that I don't have to `import { h } from 'preact'` all the time. The problem, however, is that `preact.d.ts` is not picked up if I don't import it, and instead of Preact's attributes for html, I receive global React's attributes:

[image]

With `preact` imported:

[image]

I know it seems like it doesn't matter, but I wanted to access some Preact's attributes, not global React's ones. Is it possible to point to `node_modules/preact/index.d.ts` via some kind of config? I'm not using typescript as language or compile itself, only VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

VSCode doesn't know how to use your preact typings. You should add a jsconfig.json file at the root of your project (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) where you specify your jsxFactory (it's a TS compiler option which vscode uses https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "jsxFactory": "h",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: but it does know. how do you explain the fact that it's picking up attributes without a config?

Comment: it defaults to React and it uses your import to infer Preact

Comment: when i set jsx to `preact` it goes `Value is not accepted. Valid values: "preserve", "react", "react-native".(1)` :( So basically, it's impossible what I wanna do... thx for answer anyhow

Comment: You should set jsxFactory to h, not jsx to 'preact'